# Single long-lived ios background task (voip)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app that needs to periodically (often) do some work in the background, even if the app itself is not showing. I've gotten it started and even to restart automatically after 10 minutes (600s) by declaring it a VOIP app. The app is not for App Store.

After around 300-400 seconds the system spawns a new thread (correctly), but it does not close the last one. This means that a new thread is spawned around every 600s, increasing the memory and battery consumption of my app. Not good.

**So any clues on how to close down the first spawned thread once a new one is created?**

This code starts the background handler once the app is closed down. It also periodically starts a new handler with 600s intervals

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    isInBackground = YES;
    BOOL backgroundAccepted = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
        setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{ [self startBackgroundHandler]; }];
    if (backgroundAccepted)
    {
        NSLog(@"VOIP backgrounding accepted");
    }
    [self startBackgroundHandler];
}
```

This code start a thread that periodically does some work (each 5s):

```
- (void)startBackgroundHandler
{       
    UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        while (1)
        {
            NSLog(@"BGTime left: %f", [UIApplication
               sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
            sleep(5);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am struggling for few days to achieve this facility to restart background task automatically after 10 minutes (600s). but nothing works. After seeing your question I thought it will work for me but it is not working also for me. after 10 mins when background task restarts it makes application dead in background. But how I can do this. I have posted related question but did not find any solution. Questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19288356/2459296 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19224010/2459296 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19273039/2459296

Comment: It was a long time since I coded this so can't help you more than those questions. You should create your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been struggling with this for some time now, but figured out a solution just after writing here on Stackoverflow.

Just replaced

```
while (1)
```

with

```
int localThreadId = ++threadId;
while (threadId == localThreadId)
```

where thread id is a int. So when a new thread starts, the threadId is increased and the old one stops.