# Why background task is ending after 10 minutes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am badly in need of a background task to run always, when application is in background.

It is needed for a voip application. All steps are done for voip app.

I am using following script to run background task

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
    self.bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:self.bgTask];
    }];
}
```

After using it, when application goes to background, within 10 minutes if a sip call comes `UILocalnotification` appear. but after 10 minutes if a sip call comes UILocalnotification did not appear.

Please anybody help me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `voip` as a background mode to the `UIBackgroundModes` key in your application `Info.plist` file?

Comment: Rather than `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` you could use `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:` as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a possibility that your app is crashing because of many requests in background.I hope that you already followed these steps:

There are several requirements for implementing a VoIP app:

- Add the UIBackgroundModes key to your app’s Info.plist file. Set the
  value of this key to an array that includes the voip string.

  - Configure one of the app’s sockets for VoIP usage.
  - Before moving to the background, call the
  - setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: method to install a handler to be
  - executed periodically. Your app can use this handler to maintain its
    service connection.
  - Configure your audio session to handle transitions to and from active
    use.

  To ensure a better user experience on iPhone, use the Core Telephony
  framework to adjust your behavior in relation to cell-based phone
  calls; see Core Telephony Framework Reference.
- To ensure good performance for your VoIP app, use the System
  Configuration framework to detect network changes and allow your app
  to sleep as much as possible.