# UILocalNotification doesn't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I am making a request to a server after every 30 seconds to get `Y` or `N` using an `NSTimer`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSTimer *notifyTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(httpRequest) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];//7200.0
    [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:notifyTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    return YES;
}


-(NSString *)httpRequest {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:192.168.10.67/t.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:25];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *dataReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    NSString *stringReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReply encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

   if([stringReply isEqualToString:@"Y"]) {
      [self showLocalNotification];
   }
}
```

If response is `Y` I am registering a `UILocalNotification` which will fire in a second.

```
-(void)showLocalNotification {
    NSLog("Notification is here.");
    NSString *msg = @"test message";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    UILocalNotification *_localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    _localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
    _localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    _localNotification.alertBody = msg;
    _localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    _localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:_localNotification];
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:_localNotification];
}
```

`UILocalNotification` does not show notification alert to user and does not print log  when application is in background.

When the application comes back into the foreground then it prints all the logs statements at once.  What am I doing wrong?

Also, it is a VoIP application. and UIBackgroundMode has voip and audio set.

Comment: You are missing an entire topic here.  iOS doesn't just let you run in the background.  You can read up on scheduling long running background tasks, but you still only have a limited amount of time.  It seems to me that what you really want is a *remote* push notification from your server instead of bothering it every 30 seconds.

Comment: It is a sample of code from my a VOIP application. all is going ok with my app. but when app is in background and a incoming call comes then I am trying to show a UILocalNotification to user. It can be done by a background task but it has a time limitation 10 mins. I can not it to be made long running the task. I have trying to long run using various code.

Comment: Another question for same kind of problem is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19273039/2459296 but not getting any solution. Can you help me.

Comment: You are likely going over your limit for VOIP by unnecessarily pinging your server every 30 seconds.  Again, why don't you make a remote notification instead?

Comment: Nevermind, I just looked it up and you can wake your app 15 times in 300 seconds, so 30 second pinging won't cause that.  The second point still remains.

Comment: When the incoming call arrives(your server notices your app through tcp, does't it?), your app can run it's code in the background.